# Convert command line arguments to list in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, command-line, elisp, command-line-arguments

In an automated Emacs Lisp `--batch/--script` script I need to process the command line arguments given to the script.

I've gotten as far as getting the arguments into a list of the the form:

```lisp
("--aaa=bbb" "--ccc=ddd=eee" "--blah")
```

Now, I need to convert them to a list of the form:

```lisp
(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd=eee") ("blah"))
```

In Python I'd write something like;

```py
   output = []
   for v in input:
     output.append(v[2:].split("=", 1))
```

But have been unable to convert that code to Emacs Lisp. I found [Elisp split-string function to split a string by . character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236196/elisp-split-string-function-to-split-a-string-by-character) but wasn't able to figure out how to make it only split on the first equals.

I was heading down a route of using `(substring "abcdefg" x x)` with `(search)` from the `cl` package but it felt like there should be a better way? I think also want to use `(mapc '<function> input)` where function does the `v[2:].split("=",1)` part.

Comment: Note, in the original post the desired result was `(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd") ("blah"))`. That is what my first solution delivers. The solution for the new demand `(("test") ("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd=eee"))` is now added to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split-string`. See the following code example.

```lisp
(setq cmd-line '("--aaa=bbb" "--ccc=ddd=eee" "--blah"))
(setq cmd-line (mapcar (lambda (argstr)
             (when (string-match "^--" argstr)
               (split-string (substring argstr 2) "=")))
               cmd-line))
```

The output is `(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd" "eee") ("blah"))`.
That is not exactly what you want because of `"eee"`. Maybe you can use that and just neglect `"eee"`.

If the `"eee"` is really a problem a small modification helps:

```lisp
(setq cmd-line '("--aaa=bbb" "--ccc=ddd=eee" "--blah"))

(setq cmd-line (mapcar (lambda (arg)
             (when (string-match "^--" arg)
               (setq arg (split-string (substring arg 2) "="))
               (if (cdr arg)
                   (setcdr (cdr arg) nil))
               arg))
               cmd-line))
```

The output is:

```lisp
(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd") ("blah"))
```

Variant for the new requirement in the question:

```lisp
(setq cmd-line '("--aaa=bbb" "--ccc=ddd=eee" "--blah"))

(setq cmd-line (mapcar (lambda (arg)
             (when (string-match "^--\\([^=]*\\)\\(?:=\\(.*\\)\\)?" arg)
               (let ((opt (match-string 1 arg))
                 (val (match-string 2 arg)))
                 (if val
                 (list opt val)
                   (list opt)))))
            cmd-line))
```

The output is:

```
(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ddd=eee") ("blah"))
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I had gotten as far as your first example but ran into the "eee" problem. I don't quite understand how your second example works? Could you explain further?

Comment: Hi Tobias, I finally tested your second example and it doesn't fix the "eee" issue.

Comment: @tim-mithro-ansell That is interesting because it runs fine for me. I added the output I got in the scratch buffer. (Could you run it in the scratch buffer exactly as it is? Best regards, Tobias

Comment: @tim-mithro-ansell Now, I read the edit of your question. You added a new requirement. In the former version you demanded `("ccc" "ddd")` for `--ccc=ddd=eee`. Now, you demand `("ccc" "ddd=eee")`. I will modify my answer to meet this demand when I have some spare time.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I got my example wrong. Thanks for the fixed version, it works perfectly!